# Joining domain. External DNS issue

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I have internal domain setup as corp.example.com however when I try to join it computers cant find it. When I ping corp.example.com I am getting response from my external example.com

Problem is that for some reason computers are looking for corp on example.com (external) instead of internal. How can this be fixed. I know that I can add entry to hosts file but I am looking for more elegant (proper) solution.

Thank you,

Answer (score 6):

You should run DNS on your Domain Controllers and host an Active Directory Integrated DNS zone for your AD there. This should be automatically configured after running `dcpromo` and opting to install the DNS Server role (I assume that you already are doing this. It's a basic step to setting up AD).

**Then, your Windows clients should be configured to use your internal DNS servers for DNS resolution.**

You can set this a few ways. The best way is to configure your internal DHCP server to tell your DHCP clients to use the internal server(s). This can be configured by setting DHCP Option 6 to the IP address(es) of your Domain Controller(s). *Please, don't use a hosts file entry for this*

If you still wish to use your external resolver for external DNS lookups, just set a global forwarder from your internal AD DNS servers to your external DNS resolver. At no time should your internal domain-joined workstations use any DNS server other than the ones that host your Active Directory zones.

Comment: Where can I get more information on setting up global forwarder?

Comment: Well, google is your friend. I'd search something like `"set global forwarder microsoft dns server"` After you've done that and read the relevant documentation, if you're still having problems configuring that, you can always ask another question here.

Comment: +1 for "Please, don't use a hosts file entry for this."  I actually saw that this week (and man did it cause some hard-to-troubleshoot issues), which just about made my head explode.  Fortunately, the last admin didn't leave a forwarding address, so I'm not in jail. >:/

Comment: "The best way is to configure your internal DHCP server to tell your DHCP clients to use the internal server(s)." But I don't have DHCP role installed on this server. I was using DHCP on the router. Is that bad idea? What to do in that case?

Comment: If you must you the crappy DHCP server on your router, configure it to hand out your AD DNS servers.